# Using a CQL Intersects filter with WFS GetFeature request in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wfs, cql-filter, getfeature

I am using OpenLayers to create a web app which allows users to define a polygon as an area of interest, and then query the features which fall within the bounding box and return the data to present it in a few other forms, like a pie chart for example. Right now, I am using the bbox parameter in my WFS GetFeature request. However, the features being returned by the request are almost completely wrong. [Here is a link](http://129.187.45.33/TimeServer) to a prototype of the app to see what I mean. If you open the statistics panel on the side bar, it gives you instructions to generate results which appear on the same panel.

From what I've read, the CQL Intersects filter may be a better solution to query features, but my attempts have not been successful. I have tried quite a few ways to use the CQL filter but have not gotten it to work quite right just yet.

```
const params = {
      service: "WFS",
      version: "2.0.0",
      request: "GetFeature",
      typename: "timeseries:U2006_CLC2000_V2020_20u1_3857,timeseries:U2012_CLC2006_V2020_20u1U2012_CLC2006_V2020_20u1," +
      "timeseries:U2018_CLC2012_V2020_20u1U2018_CLC2012_V2020_20u1,timeseries:U2018_CLC2018_V2020_20u1U2018_CLC2018_V2020_20u1",
      srsName: "EPSG:3857",
      outputFormat: "text/xml; subtype=gml/3.2",
      cql_filter: "Intersects(geom,POLYGON((" + minx + " " + miny + "," + maxx + " " + maxy + "))",
      // bbox: extent.join(',') + ",EPSG:3857"
  };

  $.ajax('https://thawing-waters-16552.herokuapp.com/https://clc-timeseries.gaf.de/wfs?', {
      type: "GET",
      data: params,
      dataType: "xml",
      contentType: "text/xml; subtype=gml/3.2"
  }).then(data => {doing stuff with data here})
```

I am getting a 400 Bad Request Error when requesting it as it is above.

Comment: @Ian Turton  That does not answer how to construct a polygon geometry filter.  Based on this over-complicated example https://labs.os.uk/public/os-data-hub-examples/os-features-api/wfs-example-intersects (choose OpenLayers from the dropdown for OL code) here is the same code avoiding turf and unnecessary transforms between EPSG:3857 and EPSG:4326 
http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/wfsfilter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter should be an XML string.   Where polygon is a single ring OpenLayers polygon geometry, e.g. you have drawn a polygon as in https://jsfiddle.net/0bjk6u7L/ you should be able to set it up similar to this:

```
const coords = polygon.getCoordinates()[0].join(' ');

const xml = '<ogc:Filter>' +
      '<ogc:Intersects>' +
      '<ogc:PropertyName>SHAPE</ogc:PropertyName>' +
      '<gml:Polygon srsName="EPSG::3857">' +
      '<gml:outerBoundaryIs>' +
      '<gml:LinearRing>' +
      '<gml:coordinates>' + coords + '</gml:coordinates>' +
      '</gml:LinearRing>' +
      '</gml:outerBoundaryIs>' +
      '</gml:Polygon>' +
      '</ogc:Intersects>' +
      '</ogc:Filter>';


const params = {
      service: "WFS",
      version: "2.0.0",
      request: "GetFeature",
      typename: "timeseries:U2006_CLC2000_V2020_20u1_3857,timeseries:U2012_CLC2006_V2020_20u1U2012_CLC2006_V2020_20u1," +
      "timeseries:U2018_CLC2012_V2020_20u1U2018_CLC2012_V2020_20u1,timeseries:U2018_CLC2018_V2020_20u1U2018_CLC2018_V2020_20u1",
      srsName: "EPSG:3857",
      outputFormat: "text/xml; subtype=gml/3.2",
      filter: xml,
  };
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the suggestion. I looked at the fiddle you posted and saw it working, and tried integrating it into my request, however it is matching all of the features from my layers I'm requesting.

Comment: @jessefriend No matter what I tried, I got the same results as you: all features. It looks like it's server's fault.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried quite a few things now as well and still no luck. I'll mark Mike's answer as correct as it solves the original intersects question though

Comment: It should be possible to construct the entire request in XML using https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_WFS-WFS.html#writeGetFeature with the filter specified by https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_filter_Intersects-Intersects.html  I could not get it to work with my example, but I have it working now https://jsfiddle.net/z3jw1a0f/

Comment: Replacing the filter in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs-getfeature.html with an intersects filter it works when I leave the `geometryName` parameter undefined https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-wfs-getfeature-forked-mpirb?file=/main.js